# How do i delete every character except every 8th character in unix

Tags: unix, terminal

I have a file code that look like this:

```
lqjzpvfyimberiaznkerbdozuqtwysbnxftldcze oukasyjelpnsiujsjaeotcqtivvadno ymmijtvcjfpkxtrlfswjomgakltkzzdixjatzwirgbtiiygerzpnbovmkdqhskhekuusovpnsmjubmltyfxmpxn zirhbrclluzwygwecwxvnho dmvcwrzmvrzjxbzecqfkkdaiodyawpnlmszjzcnlmqhkiuzevxuqeeludrkvwokrauvciwv aholqeeopdnvrnwsnybhadq
```

I want to keep the first character than delete the next 7 than keep the next one, etc to get something like this

```
linux est clairement le meilleur os
```

what can I use to get this

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "lqjzpvfyimberiaznkerbdozuqtwysbnxftldcze oukasyjelpnsiujsjaeotcqtivvadno ymmijtvcjfpkxtrlfswjomgakltkzzdixjatzwirgbtiiygerzpnbovmkdqhskhekuusovpnsmjubmltyfxmpxn zirhbrclluzwygwecwxvnho dmvcwrzmvrzjxbzecqfkkdaiodyawpnlmszjzcnlmqhkiuzevxuqeeludrkvwokrauvciwv aholqeeopdnvrnwsnybhadq" | sed 's/\(.\)......./\1/g'
linux est clairement le meilleur os
```

You can use sed as an example. it is a tool that can be used to transform patterns in a stream, line by line.

the command sed 's/\(.\)......./\1/g' does:

- s means substitution the command looks like s/-pattern-/-replace-/
- the pattern \(.\)....... says . means any char
- the \( \) tell it to capture the first char in a group (group 1 because it is the first)
- the other 7 '.' are the 7 characters to match for a full set of 8
- the replace is set to \1 which says replace the whole pattern (8 char) with the one in group 1 referenced as \1
- the g at the end tells sed to repeat the pattern until the end of the line (which will match the first 8 char then the next 8 etc.. till the end of the line.